# passport-jwt in nodejs always return unauthorized

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Below is sample code with demo credentials:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var passport=require('passport');
var morgan=require('morgan');
var jwt=require('jwt-simple');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send({'status':'success'});
});

var jwtStrategy=require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
opts.secretOrKey = 'admin686d86';
opts.issuer = "localhost";
opts.audience = "localhost";

passport.use(new jwtStrategy(opts,function(jwt_payload, done){
    console.log("In JWT Strategy");
    console.log(jwt_payload);
    return done(null,{id:203});
}));

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
    var token=jwt.encode({id:203},opts.secretOrKey);
    res.send({success:true,token:token});
});

app.get('/dashboard',passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}),function(req,res){
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log(jwt.decode(req.headers.authorization,opts.secretOrKey));
    res.send({status:'success'});
});

app.listen(5000);
```

When I try to login, I successfully get a token, but when I use that token and paste in header I get unauthorized. It doesn't even prints "In JWT Strategy" in console. But when I remove `passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false})` it prints data. I know there is some silly mistake but don't know where. I am totally new in node.js so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add audience and issuer during token creation:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    var token = jwt.encode({
        id: 203,
        aud: 'localhost',
        iss: 'localhost'
    }, opts.secretOrKey);

    res.send({ success: true, token: token });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()`, try using `extractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')`. that should do the magic.